# CSS loosing its effect while site loads

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

http://hasmun.org/

As you can see , the elements of the list on the right is white until background image kicks in.
I dont know which files i should provide you in order to answer my question. I will edit them in as you ask.

I changed the color of the elements using custom.css file provided by theme designer.

```
#main > div > div.sidebar.sidebar1.box.sidebar_absolute > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > ul > li.page_item > a{
color: #FFF;
}

#main > div > div.sidebar.sidebar1.box.sidebar_absolute > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a{
color: #FFF;
}
```

Thanks

Edit: I can see the rule above being active , using chrome's Inspect Element feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this on your custom.css

```
.main_menu .menu a {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to somehow move up the custom.css stylesheet loading in the PHP order.

the theme's PHP is loading the base stylesheet
then the background
then the custom.css.

you need to alter that order.

Comment: i thought custom.css should be loaded last so it can override the others?

Comment: @user3194926, yes, that's correct. it should be loaded after the first stylesheet, but before the background image.